# I need a SQL totals table to update automatically with running totals. Should I use triggers or merge (with php)? How do I combine 3 triggers into 1?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have tried the following three statements and am unsure of how to combine them:

```
CREATE TRIGGER upd_totals 
AFTER INSERT ON pc12_status 
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO total_hrs (acft_hrs, date_flight, acft_tail)
SELECT hrs_end, flight_date, tail_no FROM acft_status
INNER JOIN total_hours ON acft_status.tail_no = total_hrs.acft_tail;
```

&

```
CREATE TRIGGER total_calc_prop
AFTER INSERT ON total_hrs
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE total_hrs SET prop_hrs = (SELECT s.flight_date, s.tail_no, s.flight_hrs
SUM(s.flight_hrs) OVER (PARTITION BY s.tail_no) AS prop_hrs 
FROM acft_status s);
```

&

```
CREATE TRIGGER total_calc_eng
AFTER INSERT ON total_hrs
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE total_hrs SET engine_hrs = (SELECT s.flight_date, s.tail_no, s.flight_hrs
SUM(s.flight_hrs) OVER (PARTITION BY s.tail_no) AS engine_hrs 
FROM acft_status s);
```

I have the following two tables with data

**acft_status**

```
 flight_date  flight_hrs  tail_no  hrs_end  hrs_start 

 2017-12-31      100.0      1378     100.0     0.0
```

**total_hrs**

```
 date _flight  acft_tail  acft_hrs  engine_hrs  prop_hrs 

 2017-12-31      1378      100.0       98.5       96.5
```

Anytime I add data to the acft_status table, I need the flight_hrs to automatically sum with the previous entry in both the engine_hrs and prop_hrs fields while copying the hrs_end to the acft_hrs field:

```
INSERT INTO acft_status (flight_date, flight_hrs, tail_no, hrs_end, hrs start) 
VALUES ("2018-01-01", 1.3, 1378, 101.3, 100.0);
```

Would then update total_hrs to:

**total_hrs**

```
 date _flight  acft_tail  acft_hrs  engine_hrs  prop_hrs 

 2017-12-31      1378      100.0       98.5       96.5   

 2017-12-31      1378      101.3       99.8       97.8
```

When I try to run all three triggers, I receive  "Can't update table 'total_hrs' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.".

I am running MariaDB 10.2 which allows for `FOLLOW` and `PROCEED` to be added to triggers. Supposedly, it lets you run multiple triggers on one event.

Are triggers the most efficient way to do this? If so, how do I combine them to run automatically? Should I try a `MERGE` instead and trigger it from a query using php????

Comment: Is the total hours table even necessary

Comment: @Strawberry I have been debating that. If the prop and engine_hrs were always equal to acft_hrs, I would just use a `SELECT` statement to query for the information. Unfortunately they are different and may change again in the future. I just want to make sure that the code written now won't have to be updated in that event. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Do the arithmetic when you need to `SELECT` it, not as you `INSERT`.